# Scala mutable and immutable types

Tags: scala

Scala has List, Set, Map.

List and Map has a way to create objects using new. If we don't use, immutable companion objects are there.

But List has only immutable variation.

Why is there a difference? I understand arrays are mutable but not purpose as Lists. Isn't in Scala?

Thinking from java perspective!!

Answer (score 0):

Scala `List` is not a general term, as in Java; it's a very specific data structure, a [cons list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists). A closer equivalent to Java `List` is `scala.collection.Seq`.